# Proportional hazards model with lognormal baseline hazard in R?

Tags: r, survival, lognormal-distribution, proportional-hazards

I would like to fit a proportional hazards model with log normal baseline hazard in R. I have found several options for the semiparametric Cox proportional hazards, but I have not found a package to do parametric ph survival.

Is there a package to do this?

I have checked the packages: `survival`, `flexsurv`, and `eha` without sucess, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Have you looked at the `survival::survreg` function?

Comment: @DWin As far as I understand "=`survreg() fits accelerated failure models, not proportional hazards models`.  See: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5564_bc9e2d9a458c4660aa82882df90b7a6b.html

Comment: Some AFT models are also PH ones. The Weibull and Poisson  models are both PH. I'm not sure that log normal ones can be PH.

Comment: The Weibull (including exponential as a special case) is the *only* model that's both PH and AFT.

Answer (score 1):

As the [manual page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eha/eha.pdf) for the `phreg()` function in the R [`eha` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=eha) says:

> the standard lognormal and loglogistic distributions are not closed under proportional hazards.

That is, if you try to impose a proportional hazards (PH) assumption of covariate effects on a lognormal baseline function, the resulting distribution need not be lognormal. The proposed workaround in that package is:

> The lognormal and loglogistic baseline distributions are extended to a three-parameter family by adding a "proportionality" parameter (multiplying the baseline hazard function).

Nevertheless: "The lognormal and loglogistic distributions are included on an experimental basis for the moment. Use with care, results may be unreliable!"

The standard 2-parameter location-scale survival modeling with a lognormal baseline, as performed by the `aftreg()` function suggested in another answer, is not a proportional hazards (PH) model. It's an accelerated failure time (AFT) model. Only the Weibull family (with its special case of the exponential distribution) is closed under both PH and AFT models.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it can be done using the `aftreg` command from the `eha` R package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eha/eha.pdf

Comment: As the name `aftreg` suggests, this doesn't fit a proportional hazards model; it fits an accelerated failure model just as `survival::survreg` does.