# How to parameterize covariates in parametric time to event model (lognormal distribution)

Tags: survival, predictor, parametric

I have a parametric time to event model for survival data and I found that a lognormal distribution has the lowest objective function value for a base model. Below is the hazard function for the lognormal parametric model:

$$ h(t) =\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}=\frac{e^{-\frac12\cdot\left(\frac{\log(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t\cdot\sigma\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}}}{\left(1-\Phi\left[\frac{\log(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right]\right) }$$

I have incorporated covariates into the model in two different ways:

1. I added covariate effects to the "$\mu$" term.
2. I added covariate effects to the entire hazard as indicated below:

$$ h(t) =\frac{f(t)}{S(t)}=\frac{e^{-\frac12\cdot\left(\frac{\log(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t\cdot\sigma\cdot\sqrt{2\pi}}}{\left(1-\Phi\left[\frac{\log(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right]\right)} \cdot Covariates $$

Are there any issues with parameterizing covariates like I did for the second option? The second option results in a lower objective function value and the visual predictive checks are superior compared to parameterizing the covariate effects on the "μ" term. I think that the second parameterization effectively shifts the hazard up or down depending on the covariate value, so it seems reasonable to me. I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Please note that this is a Mathjax-enabled site. Please yse the same to write your equations rather than using an image. I have added one. For help, check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: @User1865345, thank you for updating one of the equations in LaTeX. I have updated the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 uses a lognormal distribution as the basis for an accelerated failure time model. Incorporating covariate effects into the location parameter means that changes in covariate values stretch or shrink the time axis. That maintains the overall form of the resulting survival curves as lognormal. That's a typical way of constructing a lognormal survival model. See [these course notes](https://grodri.github.io/survival/ParametricSurvival.pdf) for a succinct explanation.

Method 2 starts with a lognormal baseline survival distribution and then multiplies the hazard function by a function of covariate values. That places a proportional hazards assumption on the covariate effects. You can certainly do that. As discussed on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/572931/28500), that approach is implemented for example in the `phreg()` function of the R [`eha` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=eha), although that's "on an experimental basis at the moment."

A potential drawback, also noted there, is that the lognormal distribution family isn't closed under a proportional hazards model. Thus the resulting survival curves for non-baseline covariate values won't be strictly lognormal.

If you want to keep a consistent distribution family for all covariate values under a proportional hazards assumption, the Weibull distribution is a standard choice. If you don't need a parametric form, then a Cox survival regression can be followed by extraction of an empirical baseline cumulative hazard function.

I'd recommend that you not put too much emphasis on  having "found that a lognormal distribution has the lowest objective function value for a base model." There's a risk that a lognormal might represent a very good fit to your current data set but not necessarily one that will extend the best to new data, particularly as you seem to be in a proportional hazards rather than accelerated failure time situation with respect to covariate effects.

Comment: Thank you EdM for the reply.

Comment: Do you have any references for further reading about "the lognormal distribution family isn't closed under a proportional hazards model"? Also, the covariate values in my model are baseline covariate values, expect for one covariate which is a model parameter from another model.

Comment: Regarding the proportional hazards assumption, I had tested the covariates using cox.zph() and a simple coxph() model but the result from cox.zph() was significant for a covariate and for global which means the proportional hazard assumption is violated. In both method 1 and method 2 in the parameteric model the covariates are incorporated into the model are parameterized in different ways, for example one is exp(1.58*(covariate-0.54)) while another is ((covariate/median)**-1.97). Do these parameterizations need to be retested in the coxph() model?

Comment: I think I will use Method 1 even though the visual predictive check doesn't look as good as method 2 since the proportional hazard assumption is likely violated for this set of covariates.

Comment: I believe this is a new link to the Princeton Parameteric survival course notes: /https://grodri.github.io/survival/ParametricSurvival.pdf the other link you specified did not work for me.

Comment: @ErikHahn thanks for finding an unbroken link. Improperly modeling the functional form of a covariate can lead to apparent violation of proportional hazards (PH). So yes, any re-parameterization must be re-tested for PH. That might be part of your problem. Unless you have strong theoretical justification for your parameterizations, flexible regression splines for continuous covariates, or a generalized additive model, might be a better approach. The notes for the `eha` package are my reference for the lack of closure of lognormal under PH. Princeton notes show closure under PH for Weibull.